# How can I ensure that a transaction isn't repeated if my first attempt fails to get a response and I try the transaction again?

Tags: transactions, rpc, jsonrpc-api, cluster, network

Let's say I use the JSON RPC "sendTransaction" call to perform a transaction that sends some tokens to an account, but some communication mishap happens and I get no response after performing the call. At that moment, my system is left without knowing when the failure happened: did connection failure occur on its way to the Solana cluster or did connection failure occur in the response on its way back from the Solana cluster. I am in a state of not knowing if the transaction was successful or not.

One solution is to try it again and hope for a response. But if I do that, I might be sending the tokens twice. Alternatively, I might assume that the transaction worked, but it may not have. Either way, I don't have a response signature to query the cluster to double-check.

What is the best practice way to ensure robustness in this regard when performing Solana transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a full guide on [retrying transactions](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/retrying-transactions.html#retrying-transactions)

If the initial `blockhash` is still valid, it is possible for both transactions to be accepted by the network. To an end-user, this would appear as if they unintentionally sent the same transaction twice.

The `blockhash` is used to prevent duplications and eliminate stale transactions.

Once you send a transaction, you could use `connection.confirmTransaction(txSignature)` to subscribe and listen for transaction confirmation. Once the `latestBlockhash` has changed, and you haven't received confirmation, you have an assurance that the transaction never succeeded.